# Run powershell through winexe/psexec

Tags: ubuntu, powershell, windows-server-2012, psexec

I'm trying to connect to a Windows 2012 server from Ubuntu.

```
winexe --user <USER> --password <SERVER> //SERVER cmd.exe
```

works just fine.

However,

```
winexe --user <USER> --password <SERVER> //SERVER powershell.exe`
```

just hangs.

It displays:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

but after that it just hangs and won't respond to keypresses.

Is there a parameter I need to pass to powershell to get it to run in interactive mode or anything?

*EDIT*

If I run the above command through strace, it seems to be waiting for the server to send something back.

```
epoll_wait(4, {}, 1, 10)                = 0
epoll_wait(4, {}, 1, 10)                = 0
epoll_wait(4, {}, 1, 10)                = 0
```

Comment: Did you try [`--interactive=1` and `--system`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17633077/995714)? [Managing Windows Powershell from Linux terminal](http://serverfault.com/q/638659/343888)

Answer (score 1):

Try

> `winexe --interactive=1 --user<USER> --password <SERVER> //SERVER powershell.exe`

Comment: That doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to run the command directly using single quote. For example listing the processes can be done as follows:

```
winexe -U "Domain\PC-Name" //IP Address 'powershell.exe Get-Process'
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell seems a "Windows Gui Program", which tries to interact with the desktop. Obviously this is not possible, if connected from remote (maybe in Windows XP). To be interactive and connect the input of the powershell to stdin use "-Command -".

Which lets the powershell interact with stdin. You can type commands and see the output, but you do not get the prompt from powershell.

Comment: no, powershell is a console tool. It can be called from cmd just like bash

Answer (score 0):

Winexe sounds quite outdated and does not state supporting Windows Server 2008 and newer versions of Windows.

PowerShell went open source, you can download Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 `.deb` packages from GitHub:
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

After installing it you can remotely connect to the Windows Server 2012 machine with the [`Enter-PSSession`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession) PowerShell cmdlet.